# The difference between comma and | in erlang

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I am trying to create a function that returns the last element of a list.
However something is kinda strange here.

```
last([X,[]]) -> X;
last([_X|Xs]) -> last(Xs).
```

This returns a no-matching clause error. But if I change the first line into `last([X|[]]) -> X;` it will work correctly. I think both of lines mean the same thing but it clearly has different results. Am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comma separates list elements while a `|` separates the head of a list from its tail. `[X,[]]` is a list of two elements, `X` and the empty list `[]`. But `[X|[]]` is a list of one element, `X`, with an empty tail.

BTW you might just use [`lists:last/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#last-1) instead of writing your own function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am doing this because I think writing raw functions by myself would be better to train my skills.
In addition, can I ask then what about `last([X]) -> X` ? Does it work the same way as `last[X|[]]`?

Comment: Yes. You can verify this if you go into the Erlang shell and enter this: `[1] = [1|[]].` (here I chose to use the value `1` but you can use any value as long as it's the same on both sides of the `=`). This is like an assertion, stating that `[1]` is a match for `[1|[]]`. The result shows this to be true; if they weren't a match we'd get a `badmatch` exception instead.

Comment: @user2129773 Regarding `[1] = [1|[]]`, you might find some background information about the idea of "cons lists" useful. Equipped with some background knowledge you will start recognizing these structures all over the place dressed in various syntax in various languages: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html